# how to solve Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my ajax code :

```
$('#clinte_broker').click(function(){
    console.log('soy un btn l');

    var data = new FormData($("#cliente_broker")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: '/controlpublicacion/agregar_cliente.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : data,
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('los datos se guardaron correctamente');
        }
    })
});
```

I do not understand what the problem, please help me  thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To get formdata object to work with jQuery.ajax you need to set `processData` and `contentType` to false.

```
var data = new FormData($("#cliente_broker")[0]);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url: '/controlpublicacion/agregar_cliente.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('los datos se guardaron correctamente');
    }
})
```

Also `#cliente_broker` should be a form, use `data.append` to add a field.